# How to crop a polygonal area from an image in a WinForm pictureBox?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, crop

How can I crop a part of an image with a polygon? For example I have 6 coordinates and I would like to cut this part of an image.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make the `List` of `Points` into a Polygon, then into a `GraphicsPath` and then into a `Region` and after `Graphics.Clip(Region)` you can `Graphics.DrawImage` and are done..:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();   // a Graphicspath
gp.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());        // with one Polygon

Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(555,555);  // ..some new Bitmap
                                    // and some old one..:
using (Bitmap bmp0 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\test_xxx.png"))
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
{
    G.Clip = new Region(gp);   // restrict drawing region
    G.DrawImage(bmp0, 0, 0);   // draw clipped
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp1;  // show maybe in a PictureBox
}
gp.Dispose();
```

Note that you are free to choose the `DrawImage` location anywhere, including in the negative area to the left and top of the origin..

Also note that for 'real' cropping some (at least 4) of your points should hit the target `Bitmap`'s borders! - Or you can use the `GraphicsPath` to get its bounding box:

```
RectangleF rect = gp.GetBounds();
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap((int)Math.Round(rect.Width, 0), 
                         (int)Math.Round(rect.Height,0));
..
```

Comment: But rectangle has only 4 edges. Isn't that an issue?

Comment: The bounding box is __not meant for cropping__ but to detemnie the __minimal target rectangle__ for the target bitmap size. For the cropping the graphicspath&clip is needed. Using the bounds of the graphicspath is a handy way instead of analyzing all those points..

Comment: Didn't work at first - had to mess with the clip coordinates to be zero based