# Free-form selection crop C#

Tags: c#

How can I make a free-form selection (like in paint or photoshop) in a picture box and then crop that selection and save it to a folder? 
I already did a rectangle crop but I want that free-form selection..

Here is my rectangle crop:

```
Image img;
    bool mouseClicked;
    Point startPoint = new Point();
    Point endPoint = new Point();

    Rectangle rectCropArea;

    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnLoad(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        loadPrimaryImage();
    }

    private void loadPrimaryImage()
    {
        img = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\images.jpg");
        PictureBox1.Image = img;
    }

    private void PicBox_MouseUp(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseClicked = false;
        if ((endPoint.X != -1)) {
            Point currentPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            Y1.Text = e.X.ToString();
            Y2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
        }

        endPoint.X = -1;
        endPoint.Y = -1;
        startPoint.X = -1;
        startPoint.Y = -1;
    }

    private void PicBox_MouseDown(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseClicked = true;
        startPoint.X = e.X;
        startPoint.Y = e.Y;
        //Display coordinates
        X1.Text = startPoint.X.ToString();
        Y1.Text = startPoint.Y.ToString();

        endPoint.X = -1;
        endPoint.Y = -1;

        rectCropArea = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size());
    }

    private void PicBox_MouseMove(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);


        if ((mouseClicked)) {
            if ((endPoint.X != -1)) {
                //Display Coordinates
                X1.Text = startPoint.X.ToString();
                Y1.Text = startPoint.Y.ToString();
                X2.Text = e.X.ToString();
                Y2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
            }

            endPoint = ptCurrent;

            if ((e.X > startPoint.X & e.Y > startPoint.Y)) {
                rectCropArea.Width = e.X - startPoint.X;
                rectCropArea.Height = e.Y - startPoint.Y;


            } else if ((e.X < startPoint.X & e.Y > startPoint.Y)) {
                rectCropArea.Width = startPoint.X - e.X;
                rectCropArea.Height = e.Y - startPoint.Y;
                rectCropArea.X = e.X;
                rectCropArea.Y = startPoint.Y;

            } else if ((e.X > startPoint.X & e.Y < startPoint.Y)) {
                rectCropArea.Width = e.X - startPoint.X;
                rectCropArea.Height = startPoint.Y - e.Y;
                rectCropArea.X = startPoint.X;
                rectCropArea.Y = e.Y;

            } else {
                rectCropArea.Width = startPoint.X - e.X;
                rectCropArea.Height = startPoint.Y - e.Y;
                rectCropArea.X = e.X;
                rectCropArea.Y = e.Y;
            }

            PictureBox1.Refresh();

        }

    }

    private void PicBox_Paint(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen drawLine = new Pen(Color.Red);
        drawLine.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(drawLine, rectCropArea);
    }

    private void btnCrop_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox2.Refresh();

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height);
        Graphics g = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics();

        if (!(CheckBox1.Checked)) {
            g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox2.Width, PictureBox2.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            sourceBitmap.Dispose();

        } else {
            int x1 = 0;
            int x2 = 0;
            int y1 = 0;
            int y2 = 0;
            try {
                x1 = Convert.ToInt32(CX1.Text);
                x2 = Convert.ToInt32(CX2.Text);
                y1 = Convert.ToInt32(CY1.Text);
                y2 = Convert.ToInt32(CY2.Text);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter valid Coordinates (only Integer values)");
            }

            if (((x1 < x2 & y1 < y2))) {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
            } else if ((x2 < x1 & y2 > y1)) {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x2, y1, x1 - x2, y2 - y1);
            } else if ((x2 > x1 & y2 < y1)) {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, y1 - y2);
            } else {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x2, y2, x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
            }

            PictureBox1.Refresh();
            //This repositions the dashed box to new location as per coordinates entered.

            g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox2.Width, PictureBox2.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            sourceBitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((CheckBox1.Checked)) {
            CX1.Visible = true;
            Label10.Visible = true;
            CY1.Visible = true;
            Label9.Visible = true;
            CX2.Visible = true;
            Label8.Visible = true;
            CY2.Visible = true;
            Label7.Visible = true;

            X1.Text = "0";
            X2.Text = "0";
            Y1.Text = "0";
            Y2.Text = "0";

        } else {
            CX1.Visible = false;
            Label10.Visible = false;
            CY1.Visible = false;
            Label9.Visible = false;
            CX2.Visible = false;
            Label8.Visible = false;
            CY2.Visible = false;
            Label7.Visible = false;
        }

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        Load += OnLoad;
    }
}
```

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954503/how-to-crop-a-polygonal-area-from-an-image-in-a-winform-picturebox/30954946?s=3|1.5295#30954946)

Answer (score 0):

To copy a free-form selection you need to work with polygons.

Here is a complete example. Just paste this into a new solution and try it out (just change the path to the images).
It will create 2 pictureboxes and load an image into the first one and also create an image. Then you can click on the first image and when you have clicked 2 times it will start to show a selection, when you are finished just press the button and it will copy the selection to the other pictureBox and then save it as an png image.

What it does is to create a brush from the first image and then paint the polygon onto another image and set the other pixels in the rectangle to a background color of your choice, in this case the color: Color.Transparent.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private List<Point> _points = new List<Point>();
    private PictureBox _pictureBox1;
    private PictureBox _pictureBox2;
    private Button _button1;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Size = new Size(1366, 675);

        _pictureBox1 = new PictureBox {
            Location = new Point(12, 51),
            Size = new Size(651, 474),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        };
        _pictureBox2 = new PictureBox
        {
            Location = new Point(669, 51),
            Size = new Size(651, 474),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        };
        _button1 = new Button {
            Text = @"Copy selected area",
            Location = new Point(13, 13),
            Size = new Size(175, 23)
        };
        Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { _pictureBox1, _pictureBox2, _button1 });

        _pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"d:\temp\Hopetoun_falls.jpg");
        _points = new List<Point>();

        _pictureBox1.MouseDown += delegate(object o, MouseEventArgs args) { _points.Add(args.Location); _pictureBox1.Refresh(); };
        _pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;

        _button1.Click += button_Click;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (_points.Count < 2) {
            return;
        }

        var max = _points.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, _points[i-1].X, _points[i-1].Y, _points[i].X, _points[i].Y);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, _points[max - 1].X, _points[max - 1].Y, _points[0].X, _points[0].Y);
    }

    private static Bitmap GetSelectedArea(Image source, Color bgColor, List<Point> points) {
        var bigBm = new Bitmap(source);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bigBm)) {
            // Set the background color.
            gr.Clear(bgColor);

            // Make a brush out of the original image.
            using (var br = new TextureBrush(source)) {
                // Fill the selected area with the brush.
                gr.FillPolygon(br, points.ToArray());

                // Find the bounds of the selected area.
                var sourceRect = GetPointListBounds(points);

                // Make a bitmap that only holds the selected area.
                var result = new Bitmap(sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height);

                // Copy the selected area to the result bitmap.
                using (var resultGr = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
                    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height);
                    resultGr.DrawImage(bigBm, destRect, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                // Return the result.
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Rectangle GetPointListBounds(List<Point> points) {
        int xmin = points[0].X;
        int xmax = xmin;
        int ymin = points[0].Y;
        int ymax = ymin;

        for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++) {
            if (xmin > points[i].X) xmin = points[i].X;
            if (xmax < points[i].X) xmax = points[i].X;
            if (ymin > points[i].Y) ymin = points[i].Y;
            if (ymax < points[i].Y) ymax = points[i].Y;
        }

        return new Rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin);
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (_points.Count < 3) {
            return;
        }

        var img = GetSelectedArea(_pictureBox1.Image, Color.Transparent, _points);
        _pictureBox2.Image = img;
        _pictureBox2.Image.Save(@"d:\temp\sample.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already found an answer for this question.. should've posted it here..