# Crop an image while cropping area is not rectangle

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

How can I crop a specific area from an image while the chosen area is not a perfect rectangle?  In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKnjR.png), how can I crop the area other than red into different pieces?

Comment: An image can only be rectanglular. Looking at the image I have no idea what you want.. Maybe [something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954503/how-to-crop-a-polygonal-area-from-an-image-in-a-winform-picturebox/30954946?s=4|1.5201#30954946)

Comment: I guess it depends upon what you mean by "crop". If it is an ARGB image, (with alpha/transparency) and you wanted to make pixels of a certain color, for example, transparent, you could do Bitmap.GetPixel() and check for the color you want to hide, and adjust the alpha for that pixel I suppose.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and read a book on image-processing fundamentals or at least some tutorial...
terms that might help: aoi, roi, mask

Comment: Interesting problem - do you have any higher resolution images available?

Answer (score 0):

To isolate non-rectangular areas of an image, and/or areas based upon color, a powerful method is to use the alpha/transparency property of 32 bit images. For example, the image on the left is an original, 24 bit image (no alpha), and on the right is the result of converting that image to 32 bit, and setting the alpha = 0 for all pixels that are white or red in the original image. Effectively, this can make your image non-rectangular.

[image]

The code for this is fairly simple. The method below takes an input bitmap (24 bit), generates a blank 32 bit image, and transfers all pixels from the source to destination, setting the alpha to 0 for all white or red pixels.

```
public Bitmap ModifyAlpha(Bitmap bmap)
    {
        Bitmap bmap32 = new Bitmap(bmap.Width, bmap.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Color theColor = new Color();
        Color newColor = new Color();

        for (int i = 0; i < bmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
            {
                // Get the color of the pixel at (i,j)
                theColor = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);

                // Set the pixel color/range you want to make transparent
                if ((theColor.R > 250 && theColor.G > 250 && theColor.B > 250) ||
                    (theColor.R > 250))
                {
                    newColor = Color.FromArgb(0, theColor.R, theColor.G, theColor.B);
                    bmap32.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
                } else
                {
                    bmap32.SetPixel(i, j, theColor);
                }
            }
        }
        return bmap32;
     }
```